# helpd need with sorted tuple and linq query

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I've writen a little test case to explain my issue.

I'm somehow able to query my DB to get a list of list of tuple.

From which I want to extract a list of tuple, with no duplicate, ordered by Item1 ... which is fine,  but now I always want to remove tuple when Item2 is not sorted in descending order.

I was able to do this by creating a temporary list and then removing bad tuples.

Could you please help me do to this directly in linq  (if possible ?) ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Web.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ListListTupleTest
    {

        [TestCase]
        public void TestCaseTest_1()
        {
            var input = new List<List<Tuple<int, decimal>>>
            {
                new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>
                {
                    new Tuple<int, decimal>(5, 20),
                    new Tuple<int, decimal>(8, 10)
                },
                new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>
                {
                    new Tuple<int, decimal>(7, 17),
                    new Tuple<int, decimal>(12, 9)
                },
                new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>
                {
                    new Tuple<int, decimal>(7, 17),
                    new Tuple<int, decimal>(15, 10)
                }
            };

            var goal = new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>()
            {
                new Tuple<int, decimal>(5, 20),
                new Tuple<int, decimal>(7, 17),
                new Tuple<int, decimal>(8, 10),
                new Tuple<int, decimal>(12, 9)
            };

            var result = myFunction(input);

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(result, goal);

        }



        private List<Tuple<int, decimal>> myFunction(List<List<Tuple<int, decimal>>> myList)
        {
            var tmp = myList
                .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray())
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
                .ToList();


            var result = new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>();

            if (tmp.Any())
            {
                result.Add(tmp.First());
                decimal current = tmp.First().Item2;

                foreach (var tuple in tmp.Skip(1))
                {
                    if (tuple.Item2 < current)
                    {
                        result.Add(tuple);
                        current = tuple.Item2;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Classic loops are often the better approach if you need access to the previous or next item. A LINQ approach is often not very readable and less efficient. However, question fits better to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with Tim.  Linq gets messy when you need to compare items in a list.  Best to make code using classic loops.  I often create a help method to do the comparison and then add the helper into a linq.

Comment: The problem is not only that you have to access the previous item but you have to retain the last highest item which is not necessarily the previous item if multiple items were invalid. It's possible that the order could be `10,15,11`, then the last 11 should not be added because it is still higher than the last valid what was 10. A loop is perfect for this use case.

Comment: Exactly, my question would be how do you want to handle `10,15,11` ? Are both `15` and `11` rejected?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that loop might be a best solution here, but if you really really want to use LINQ, you can use `Aggregate` like this:

```
return myList
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray())
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<Tuple<int, decimal>>(),
        (acc, value) => value.Item2 > acc.LastOrDefault()?.Item2 ? 
                           acc : 
                           acc.Concat(new[] {value}))
    .ToList();
```

This basically replicates your loop: we start with empty set (`Enumerable.Empty<Tuple<int, decimal>>()`) and then aggregate gives values one by one to our callback. There we either return previous set as is, or adding current item to it, depending on `Item2` comparision.

You can also use `List` as accumulator instead of `Enumerable.Empty`:

```
return myList
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray())
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
    .Aggregate(new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>(),
        (acc, value) =>
        {
            var last = acc.Count > 0 ? acc[acc.Count - 1] : null;
            if (last == null || value.Item2 < last.Item2)
                acc.Add(value);
            return acc;
        }); // ToList is not needed - already a list
```

Answer (score 0):

To use LINQ for this, I use a special extension method that is based on the APL scan operator - it is like `Aggregate`, but returns all the intermediate results. In this case, I use a special variation that automatically pairs results with original data in a `ValueTuple`, and initializes the state with a `Func` on the first value:

```
public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> fnSeed, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combine) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var seed = (fnSeed(srce.Current), srce.Current);

            while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                yield return seed;
                seed = (combine(seed, srce.Current), srce.Current);
            }
            yield return seed;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it is relatively straight forward to compute your result - you do it pretty much like you state:

```
var ans = input.SelectMany(sub => sub, (l, s) => s) // flatten lists to one list
               .Distinct() // keep only distinct tuples
               .OrderBy(s => s.Item1) // sort by Item1 ascending
               .ScanPair(firstTuple => (Item2Desc: true, LastValidItem2: firstTuple.Item2), // set initial state (Is Item2 < previous valid Item2?, Last Valid Item2)
                         (state, cur) => cur.Item2 < state.Key.LastValidItem2 ? (true, cur.Item2) // if still descending, accept Tuple and remember new Item2
                                                                              : (false, state.Key.LastValidItem2)) // reject Tuple and remember last valid Item2
               .Where(statekv => statekv.Key.Item2Desc) // filter out invalid Tuples
               .Select(statekv => statekv.Value); // return just the Tuples
```